# How do I Display Images in React which are downloaded as Files & saved in a Folder on the Server with the Filepath stored in my Database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

#### Short Setup, Problem & Code Summary

### Setup

React.js, Node.js/Express.js & PostgreSQL.

I scrape an ImageUrl of a Book, download and store it in a File in an Image Folder with Node.js and store the Filepath in my postgreSQL Database AND I would like to fetch and display the Image in an `<img />` tag on my React frontend.

### Problem

The Image I Fetch from my Database through my API doesn't get displayed, eventhough I can console.log the Image Object in the devtool-console and even make a succesful Postman request with the Image-Object as JSON response.
Furthermore I can get the image even be displayed if I go to localhost:3001/image-193x278.png.
My `<img />` Tag has even the right Img src attribute displayed in the devtools (images\image-193x278.png)

In the devtool-console I get the following error:
GEThttp://localhost:3002/images/image-193x278.png
[HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]

(Note: My Frontend runs on localhost 3002 while my server & frontend are running concurrently with a proxy on 3001, but that isn't the causing Problem here)

### Code

## React Code

```
const [image, setImage] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/test', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      })
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      setImage(data);
    }
    fetchData();

  }, []);
```

I tried to get it displayed in two different ways:

```
<img className={css(styles.Image)} src={image.test_images} alt="" />
```

```
{image.map((img) => 
<img className={css(styles.Image)} src={img.test_images} alt="" />)}
```

## Server-Side

```
app.get('/test', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const image = await testdb.query('SELECT * FROM test_table');
        res.json(image.rows);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
})
```

I serve an Express Static File

```
app.use(express.static('images'));
```

I even tried two additional varients just in case

```
app.get('/test', express.static(__dirname + '../images'));
app.use(express.static('../images'));
```

Still with no succes.
I hope i could make myself understood as good as possible and I would be extremely thankful for every help thrown out my way.

Comment: what are you getting in console.log(data) ?

Comment: (1) […]
​
0: Object { test_images: "images\\image-193x278.png" }
​
length: 1
​
<prototype>: Array []

Comment: You said you can see the images on ` localhost:3001/image-193x278.png`.

Comment: But you're setting the path to `http://localhost:3002/images/image-193x278.png`. When you hit this path in the browser are you getting anything?

Comment: No I don't get anything hitting http://localhost:3002/images/image-193x278.png.

Comment: that means, the problem is with your static server. It is not serving this file. So, the problem might be either there is no file with this name or you are not setting the static folder properly

Comment: How can I redirect my Express Static file appropriatly for this example , any idea?

Comment: I found the problem. I will post the answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your static folder. The static files will be available at `localhost:3002/:filename`.

If you want to make it work under `/images` path, then you can add the path to the static declaration like

```
app.use('/images', express.static('images'))
```

Then you can hit the `localhost:3002/images/:filename`.

You can find the documentation here: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html